# Net::SFTP Hangs

Tags: perl, sftp, freeze, net-sftp

I'm using [Net::SFTP](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::SFTP) to transfer files. However, whenever I try to create a new object like so:

```
my $sftp = Net::SFTP->new('ip', user=>'user', password=>'pass');
```

It just hangs and does nothing. Does anyone know why this is? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

**Update**

Here is the debug output:

```
dev1.com: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
dev1.com: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
dev1.com: Connecting to 50.56.91.91, port 22.
dev1.com: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_4.3
dev1.com: Net::SSH::Perl Version 1.34, protocol version 2.0.
dev1.com: No compat match: OpenSSH_4.3.
dev1.com: Connection established.
dev1.com: Sent key-exchange init (KEXINIT), wait response.
dev1.com: Algorithms, c->s: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
dev1.com: Algorithms, s->c: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
dev1.com: Entering Diffie-Hellman Group 1 key exchange.
dev1.com: Sent DH public key, waiting for reply. 
dev1.com: Received host key, type 'ssh-dss'.
dev1.com: Host 'ip_here' is known and matches the host key.
dev1.com: Computing shared secret key.
dev1.com: Verifying server signature.
dev1.com: Waiting for NEWKEYS message.
dev1.com: Send NEWKEYS.
dev1.com: Enabling encryption/MAC/compression.
dev1.com: Sending request for user-authentication service.
dev1.com: Service accepted: ssh-userauth. 
dev1.com: Trying empty user-authentication request.
dev1.com: Authentication methods that can continue: publickey,gssapi-with mic,password.
dev1.com: Next method to try is publickey.
dev1.com: Trying pubkey authentication with key file '/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa2'
```

Comment: I imagine it's trying to connect and the request is falling on deaf ears. Perhaps a firewall issue?

Comment: @ikegami, but the thing is that I can use ssh from the command line. So I would think that it's probably not a firewall issue.

Comment: It seems to be ignoring your password and using a public key instead. Do you provide a password when you connect from the command line? Is the stuff in `/home/user/.ssh` correct?

Comment: When I connect from the command line I do not use a password-- it just uses my key. And I believe that the stuff in `/home/user/.ssh` is correct, because it works when I ssh from the command line. They key that it is trying to use in the debug output is the same key I use to connect from the command line.

Comment: the Net::SFTP/Net::SSH::Perl modules are not maintained any more and have lots of bugs. Try using [Net::SFTP::Foreign](https://metacpan.org/module/Net::SFTP::Foreign) instead.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the `user` and `password` options, set `debug => 1`. You will get some diagnostic output that may tell you what the problem is.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I've posted the debug output above.

Answer (score 2):

Search if your connection data is correct. Use a simple code like that showed in [Net::SFTP::Foreign](http://search.cpan.org/~salva/Net-SFTP-Foreign-1.58_02/lib/Net/SFTP/Foreign.pm) .

Comment: Thanks a lot! Net::SFTP::Foreign looks great :)